# not able to add json-lib dependency to pom

Tags: java, maven, json-lib

I am trying to add json-lib dependency to pom, but it is freaking out saying that

```
       'Missing artifact net.sf.json-lib:json-lib'
```

dependency:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

repository:

```
    <repository>
        <id>java.net2</id>
        <name>Java.net</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
```

Not sure what needs to added.

Comment: FYI You don't need that repository declaration. First of all the Java.net repo is no longer used and has been replaced by Maven Central. The Maven central URL you've configured is setup as the default in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, found the issue.

I missed adding classifier' tag in child pom.